# Sauna heater wiring help needed

Tags: electrical

I bought a heater from amazon : https://www.amazon.co.uk/ECO-WORTHY-Electric-Heater-Controller-Shower/dp/B01B2IWJNO/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8
I want to do a DIY sauna and need help with wiring as this thing comes with external control unit and is for 220V AC.
This is what I get in manual :
[image: Text]
Wiring diagram:
[image: Text]
And this is physical heater and controller:
[image: Text]
Can anybody help me out as I am not professional electricial, and could somebody show how to wire heater properly? I will be using 220V AC , as my household does not support 3 phase 400V.
I would appreciate any help, but maybe a list of what else do I need, and some **diagram how to wire it**, as i do not understand fully how do i wire heater to controler and input to heater.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you post a full model number for the unit, or a link to the manual on the manufacturer's website for that matter?

Comment: You can't install that to AC mains power.  It's not UL-listed nor TUV nor BSI nor any equivalent mark of any kind, not even a genuine CE self-certification mark. (if it has it, it's faked).  Unfortunately, Amazon used to be a respectable seller, but chose to turn themselves into eBay, and so almost everything on there is the Banggood, DealExtreme, wish.com, AliExpress junkstream.  Even the stuff that ships with Prime, because they opened up their warehouses too.  The price was too good to be true, and so it is.

Answer (score -1):

Well you better return it because it is designed to be run off 3 phase not single phase.  You can contact the manufacturer and ask if it can be run off single phase using different wiring they may support that but I seriously doubt it.